# Conditional get template part

Tags: page-template, get-posts, homepage, get-template-part

My index page look like this...

```
    <div id="ad-id">google ad code goes here </div><br />
    <div id="post-id">My posts are goes here</div>
```

I use

```
    get_template_part('index')
```

in another page template. But I want index's posts only NOT google ads.

Help me..

Thanks in advance..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `index` template, you'll want to add a conditional around your Google ad. The subject of that conditional is up to you, and will depend on your exact needs. For instance, if you want it to show on the homepage but not other pages, you can check if `is_home()`. If your needs are more abstract, you can define a global variable and set it as appropriate before your `get_template_part` call, e.g. `$GLOBALS['show_ad'] = true;` and then only display the Google ad if that's true.

### Edit: Examples

Say you want to show this only on your homepage. Here's what your index page should look like...

```
<?php if ( is_home() ) : ?>
<div id="ad-id">google ad code goes here </div><br />
<?php endif ?>
<div id="post-id">My posts are goes here</div>
```

Or, say your needs are more abstract. Here are both pages with a global variable.

**index page:**

```
<?php if ( isset( $GLOBALS['show_ad'] ) && true == $GLOBALS['show_ad'] ) : ?>
<div id="ad-id">google ad code goes here </div><br />
<?php endif ?>
<div id="post-id">My posts are goes here</div>
```

**Calling template:**

```
# Show the ad
$GLOBALS['show_ad'] = true;
get_template_part( 'index' );
```

... or...

```
# Don't show the ad
$GLOBALS['show_ad'] = false;
get_template_part( 'index' );
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I can understand little because am not php familiar more. So kindly give some example codes. It will help me.. Thanx

Comment: Kindly see this link.. http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/88171/get-template-part-with-except you can understand my exact issue.. Thanks Mr.Matthew

Comment: @Venkat see edits. Good luck, I hope this helps!